# QGIS, Rule-Based Symbology Not Working, But Feature Filter Does

Tags: qgis, symbology, sql

I'm trying to symbolize earthquake points by intensity, depth and date, I could create twelve separate layers but I thought using the rule based symbology would create a single nice and tidy layer, however I am having problems with the points displaying, they aren't. What's interesting is if I take the same SQL and put it in the Provider Feature Filter on the Source tab they do work.

I am missing something, but I don't know what, any ideas?

See attached below.

[image]

Below are two images, both use the same SQL but only the filter results in any records:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you specify what your field attributes are, does any of the symbol show up ? Have you tried one rule only : does it show up ?

Comment: None of the symbols show up, unless the same SQL is added to the Feature Provider Filter. The field attributes are time stored as QDATE and spans a year, magnitude stored as double and has values 1 - 6.5ish, and depth, also a double and goes from .5 to 30Km.

Comment: Not clear to me what 'the same SQL'  being added : can you show bothe cases by updating your question?

Comment: I've added a couple screenshots

Comment: I am not sure the expression (in the rule) is SQL and handles `Between`. It is valid in the expression editor ?

Comment: Thanks for the help Kasper! I tried both actually. IN and BETWEEN

Comment: Your date is not a date, but a string representing a date. <= and >= don't work with strings in expressions. Cast it to a date and try again.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer:
Rule based styling expressions are **not** SQL, use the expression syntax instead

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid it might be something like that, I'll have to figure something out then.